# How convert a String to a String with HTML entities?

Tags: php, python, encoding, html-entities

I am looking for a way, preferably in `python`, but `PHP` is also ok or even an online site, to convert a string like

```
"Wählen"
```

into a string like

```
"W&auml;hlen"
```

i.e. replacing each ISO 8859-1 character/symbol by its HTML entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo htmlentities('Wählen', 0, 'utf-8');
```

^ PHP

**PS**: *Learn the arguments based on where you need the encoded string to appear*:

```
// does not encode quotes
echo htmlentities('"Wählen"', 0, 'utf-8');
// encodes quotes
echo htmlentities('"Wählen"', ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: I am astonished that PHP seems to provide a better solution (i.e. a simple one-liner) as opposed to python. I like simple solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
 $html="Wählen";
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ISO-8859-1');
// OR  $html = htmlentities($html, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1');
echo $new = htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python3

```
>>> import html.entities
>>> reventities = {k:'&'+v+';' for v,k in html.entities.entitydefs.items()}
>>> "".join(reventities.get(i, i) for i in "Wählen")
'W&auml;hlen'
```

Another (probably faster) way

```
>>> toentity = {k: '&'+v+';' for k,v in html.entities.codepoint2name.items()}
>>> "Wählen".translate(toentity)
'W&auml;hlen'
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from htmlentitydefs import codepoint2name

def uni_to_html(s):
    new_s = ""
    for c in s:
        try:
            new_s += '&{};'.format(codepoint2name[ord(c)])
        except KeyError:
            new_s += c
    return new_s

print uni_to_html(u"Wählen")  # W&auml;hlen
```